# Xcode 11.2: precondition failure: imported node deleted before its value was read: 92

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I have View A from where i can navigate to View B, by using this code.

```
NavigationLink(destination: NonProfitView() {
        Text("CHANGE")
            .font(Font.system(size: 13))
            .fontWeight(.medium)
}
```

and in View B I have list that i populate by using this code.

```
List{
     ForEach(props.nonProfit.items, id: \.organization_id){ nonProfit in
          ZStack {
                  NonProfitCustomRow(nonProfit: nonProfit)
                    .padding(3)
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 10, trailing: 0))

                  NavigationLink(destination: NonProfitDetailView(nonProfit: nonProfit)) {
                     EmptyView()
                  }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
             }
        }
  }
```

But when i come back to View A by pressing back button, my app crashes saying **precondition failure: imported node deleted before its value was read: 92.**. Is it something that i am doing wrong ?

Note: 
• I am using Xcode 11.2
• App crashes on some devices and works fine for some.

Comment: At first try to update to the latest Xcode 11.4.

Comment: @Asperi For dismissing I wrote this code ' presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() ' in dispatch queue and it works